# O-Notation exercise problem to understand part of the code

Tags: java

Hello :) I have to solve some exercises regarding the O-Notation. Every exercise was okay, but one confused me and I have no idea how I can solve. Maybe somebody could explain me what I have to do to find the right O-Notation.

```
 double g(int x, int y) {
    double s = 0.0D;
    for (long i = f(x, y); i >= 0; i--) {
        s++;
    }
    return s;
}
```

My problem is the f(x, y). How do I have to understand that part?
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Apparently there's a `f` function defined somewhere. That's just a function call.

Comment: it calls the method `f` and passes `x` and `y` into it and uses the result as the starting point of the loop.

Comment: Assuming the missing `f` function is deliberate, this code runs in linear time depending on the `f` function.  Could it be said that it runs in *O( f(x,y) )* time?

Answer (score 1):

The loop iterates `f(x, y)` times.

Without the definition of the time conplexity of `f`, the most accurate description we can give is:

```
O(f(x, y))
```

——

Note that this is not that special a notation, since we already routinely describe time complexity based on other albeit standard functions, eg

```
O(log(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to decide on the correct Big-O expression, so it's no wonder that you're confused.

`g(x,y)` effectively consists of one function call `f(x,y)` and a loop with `K` iterations, where we define `K` to be the the result of the `f(x,y)` function call.

As we know nothing about the complexity of the `f(x,y)` function (e.g. is it `O(1)`, `O(x+y)`, or `O(x² + y²)` ?), we can't know its influence on the `g(x,y)` complexity.

And then we don't know how the `f(x,y)` function result `K` depends on the `x` and `y` values, so we don't know how often the loop is run.